# Adding code comments to DWT

Tags: dwt

I don't see there being any official way to add comments into the DWT building blocks in tridion, but i've come across a situation where i'd really like to add them without having them appear in the rendered/output html code.

I'm thinking of creating my own syntax for this and writing a tbb to strip them out during publishing.

Has anyone done this, or can suggest another method that works well for commenting?

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use `<tcdl:Comment>` tags - these get stripped out at request time (I think).
See [online docs](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE&lang=en-US#addHistory=true&filename=CDWebAppAPIReferenceTCDLOnly.xml&docid=link_concept_B72F4D64713F4682B61C838A013DF8F8&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&eventType=lcContent.loadDoclink_concept_B72F4D64713F4682B61C838A013DF8F8&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql?c=t&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE&lang=en-US&action=search&query=tcdl&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1372876885780&currentQuery=tcdl&currentScope=) [Login Required]

Comment: wow that's interesting, i'll give this a go

Answer (score 7):

You can use HTML comments:

```
<!-- My HTML comment -->
```

Then write a TBB strip them out; though no need for custom syntax unless you want to differentiate between your DWT logic comments and actual HTML comments that you want to keep.

Answer (score 6):

When you say creating

> your own syntax for this

... do you simply mean pre-fixing/wrapping the HTML comments with some sort of 'strip-me' identifier ... to allow some HTML comments to still push through?

```
<!-- this comment will make it through -->

<!-- debug:this is an internal comment and will be stripped on LIVE publishing -->
```

I quite like this as it's simple to use, simple to code out too and the TBB can be adapted to allow different prefixes for different comment requirements)

Answer (score 6):

Just use an expression with an empty string and a javascript comment

```
${"" /*This is a comment! */}
```